# android gif animation and button

Tags: android, animation, gif

I want to create an animate img, so when I click a button I can see the animation. 
in my project, I've just create buttons and images. In the drawable folder, I put the three png images and a frame_animation.xml, I set the images and the duration. In the java file, I put this code:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);

            myFrameAnimation=(AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
        }
    });
```

but when I run the app, the animation doesn't work (I can see only one image, not all the three image)

Comment: ... what has this to do with **animated GIF**s?

Comment: cause i want to put a GIF file. For do this, I create an frame_animation xml where I put all the extracted frames. then I fix the java code but it doesn't work.

Comment: An **animated GIF** is a different thing from an **Android Frame Animation**. It's a single file, not different files (1 per frame + 1 as the animation container). And it requires no Java code to be played (that is you can play it in a Web Browser "as is"). Here's **the Android way**: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame

Answer (score 0):

You have to also **START** the animation, setting the resource is not enough.
In your case simply add `myFrameAnimation.start();`

*Full example:*

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame_animation);

        myFrameAnimation=(AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
        myFrameAnimation.start();
    }
});
```

Seems like you just left it out by accident, since you already got the `AnimationDrawable` from your resource.